# Change image for artist in iTunes

Tags: itunes

In iTunes 11, when you view your library as "Artist List", is it possible to change the image displayed for each artist?

I'm guessing that artists can upload their own image to the iTunes store but if they don't, iTunes will choose a random album cover as artist image. Can I control this somehow?

[image: Artist images in iTunes]

Comment: Not sure if iTunes on OS X and Windows behaves *exactly* the same, so perhaps it would be better if you can add an OS tag as well.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't come across any real difference between iTunes on Windows and iTunes on Mac. So, I doubt that it's different. Also, for me, the OS doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

I just got through chatting with Apple support about this issue.  (February 2019)

iTunes populates artist photos directly from Apple's servers—artwork usually provided by the artists themselves.  iTunes doesn't allow users to add their own artist photos, nor will it use photos from album artwork in a user's library.  If iTunes ever did populate artist photos from album artwork, as has been mentioned here, that feature is gone.

It was suggested that anyone interested in this issue should report it as an enhancement request.  Here is a link to that:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 3):

It's based on the highest-rated track or album within your collection of that artist. If you make a track that contains the artwork you prefer as the artist default a 5-Star track, and then down-rate the tracks with the current default artwork. Then quit iTunes and open it again. This should change the artwork for the artist.

Comment: Confirmed by rating a track in a collection 1-star. -_-

Answer (score 0):

First you right click on the artist, and then click "get info" double click on the artwork space and then choose a picture from finder.

Comment: I don't think this will actually work (at least I couldn't get it to work). You'll probably just changing the album art for all albums of this artist.